# Multiple Sites with Django and Apache - Can't get both to work at the same time

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

We have two sites made in Django, one is a fork of the other (same project name) so we had issues with the wrong settings.py loading for the second site in mod_wsgi. So we put mod_wsgi into Daemon mode to hopefully separate the two more so this didn't happen.

One works fine when the other is either disabled or configured incorrectly. Once the second site is made to what should work, it doesn't and it brings the first one down with it, giving us an Apache 500 Error.

Here is the conf.d file we have for one of them:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess {siteName}.co.uk python-home=/var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/venv python-path=/var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}
WSGIProcessGroup {siteName}.co.uk

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}/{djangoProject}/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/venv
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName {siteName}.co.uk

  ServerAlias www.{siteName}.co.uk


  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/>

           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

           AllowOverride All

   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}/{djangoProject}>
      <Files wsgi.py>
         Require all granted
      </Files>
   </Directory>

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/{siteName}.co.uk-access.log combined

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/{siteName}.co.uk-error.log
   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,

   # alert, emerg.

   LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

**Note:** The file is the same for the two sites, except for that ***{siteName}*** is different. ***{djangoProject}*** is the same, since one is a modified clone of the other.

It also gives the error in the apache log that there was a permission denied for the mysite.log file, this file for both sites has been made to have permissions 777 through chmod, but this error still persists.

This error seems strange since when one is configured to run, it works fine, this error only occurs when both sites are attempting to run at the same time.

Anybody know what we might be missing?

***UPDATE***

Figured out the mysite.log thing, it was an incorrect config for one of the sites. However, now that that is fixed. both domains are pointing to site 2, as in Site 2 loads and works on domain 2, but domain 1 shows site 2 not site 1

Answer (score 0):

1. apache mod_wsgi only handles one virtual environment for all vhosts, so WSGIPythonHome can only be defined once
2. all other WSGIxxx definitions are specific for each vhost and therefore need to be placed inside the virtual host statement:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/vhosts/venv

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess {siteName}.co.uk python-home=/var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/venv python-path=/var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}
    WSGIProcessGroup {siteName}.co.uk

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}/{djangoProject}/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/{siteName}.co.uk/website/{djangoProject}


...
```